# Battery indicator on MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

Why doesn't the MacBook Air have a battery indicator on the device like MacBook Pro? I am used to the MacBook Pro having it turned off but I still know if the battery is full or not. What about the MacBook Air?

[image]

Comment: Welcome on AskDifferent. Have a look at the Tour: https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour. This community focuses on solving actual problems, and questions about *why* Apple does/doesn't do something are usually opinion-based and therefore don't belong here. Also, it sounds to me like you are referring to an older MBP with MagSafe 2 connector and a newer MBA that only has USB-C. All MBPs from 2016 and newer don't have MagSafe anymore.

Comment: MagSafe Connector? Battery indicator on the side of MacBook Pro 2011 ?

What indicator are you referring to? Please add an image!

Comment: yes you are right I should have uploaded a pic. Can you see it now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MacBook Air has never, and the MacBook Pro has not since the 2013 revision, had a hardware battery indicator. The one that was found on those earlier MacBook Pros is no longer present. Both computers show the battery percentage in the Menu Bar, near where the time is displayed.

If the battery is not shown there, you can open System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Battery and check "Show in Menu Bar."

[image]

Comment: My 2007 MBP has a hardware battery indicator. If you press the button on the battery between 1 and 5 green lights come on depending on charge. Perhaps it's only models with removable battery.

Comment: Ah yes, the older pre-Retina ones do have a battery indicator, but given how old (10+ years) they are I did not mention them in my post.

Comment: I've gone ahead and updated my post to include that information to avoid confusion

Comment: so there isn't that little button on the left side of the device illuminating the percentage of battery? So when Air is off you cannot see if it is fully charged or not. Also on Mac book pro there was that green and orange light on the charger. Again I suppose there isn't on Air

Comment: @Claire The button on the side was removed starting with the 2013 MacBook Pro. The light on the charger was on both the MacBook Air and the MacBook Pro but was removed starting with the 2016 MacBook Pro and the 2018 MacBook Air.

Comment: @EzekielElin you are right. no recent models have these indicators now. bit still I wonder how can I know if the battery is full while Mac is turned off.

Comment: @Claire I can confirm there is no way to do this without opening the computer in current models. Models with Mag Safe have a light - but that doesn't include current models.